# v-model no functiona en input radio

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo una existencial, la cuestión es que tengo unas API que me entrega el resultado de esta manera:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "quiz": "¿Pregunta uno?",
}
```

Lo que estoy realizando es añadir un elemento más de esta manera:

```
axios.get('api/quiz')
.then((response) => {
    this.quiz= response.data
    this.quiz.temp= null

})
```

Obtengo lo siguiente:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "quiz": "¿Pregunta uno?",
    "temp": null

}
```

La cuestión es que acabo de crear dos inputs de tipo radio:

```
{{ quiz }} // Muestro el objeto
<input type="radio" v-model="quiz.temp" value="Yes" name="radio"> Yes
<input type="radio" v-model="quiz.temp" value="No" name="radio"> No
```

> Cuando hago un clic en el radio esta no se refleja, es decir en {{
>   quiz.temp }} el valor sigue en `NULL` y no cambia a `Yes` o `No`, no
>   sé que está pasando ya que si creo esa variable dentro del `data` es
>   decir fuera del objeto si cambia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en el then response tu solito le estas diciendo que lo ponga a nulo mediante `this.quiz.temp= null`, eso es normal?.

Comment: Si.. y el problema es vue... ese objeto no esta mapeado al v-model porque lo creaste despues...

Comment: eso debe estar tirando un error al renderizar el documento.. puede ser?

Comment: https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declarando-propiedades-reactivas

Comment: @RusLan, es normal

Comment: @gbianchi♦, Revisaré la documentación, gracias!